# CSC.exe hanging while building code

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2013, build, msbuild, csc

I have a solution developed in VS 2013 containing some 20 odd projects which used to build fine initially but now for past couple of days we are facing an issue where the build randonly hangs.

I looked up in Task manager and noticed the process CSC.EXE is running but not doing anything basically it is in hanged state. If I kill the process the rest of the Build for the other projects continous.

1. The Build hangs on different projects, So not problem with one particular project in the solution.
2. I tried the same thing through Command line Argument og MSBUILD.EXE, it also exhibited the same behaviour where the build got hanged on some random project and once I killed CSC.EXE from task manager the rest of the build continued.
3. This problem is occuring even when I open VS in Admin Mode.
4. I have complete rights on the system, I am the admin.

Any suggestions/pointers are welcome.

Comment: Disable the installed anti-malware product and try again.

Comment: I had Symantec and have disabled that. Still no success.